# getting IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I keep running into the following error when pushing my data (flattened 255x255 images - (1, 65,025) through a linear neural network:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

I made a helper script to resize all of the images and store them in a directory within the project, but the main code is in the main.py file.
I am also using (trying to use) PyTorch's Dataset and Dataloader classes for batch processing.

The following code is my main.py file that has the Linear network, and training loop.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision.io import read_image
import os
import pandas as pd
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from PIL import Image

from helper_script import resize_training_images

device = (
    "cuda"
    if torch.cuda.is_available()
    else "mps"
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available()
    else "cpu"
)
EPOCHS = 50

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path_1 = os.path.join(str(self.img_dir), str(self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 2]))
        img_path_2 = os.path.join(str(img_path_1), str(self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0]))

        img = Image.open(img_path_2)
        lbl = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]

        if self.transform:
            img = self.transform(img)
        else:
            print(img.size)
            img = read_image(img_path_2)

        return img, lbl

class MyLinearNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size: tuple, channels: int=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.channels = channels
        self.input_size = input_size[0] * input_size[1] * input_size[2]

        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=self.input_size, out_features=512), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=3))

    def forward(self, x):
        if torch.is_tensor(x):
            x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)

        return logits



my_dataset = CustomImageDataset(annotations_file="faces_annotation.csv", img_dir="altered images", transform=None)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    my_net = MyLinearNetwork(input_size=(3,255,255), channels=3).to(device=device)

    x_in: torch.tensor(data=[], device=device)

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        training_data = next(iter(train_dataloader))

        # Display current epoch
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}")
        print("==================================================================")
        for i in range(my_dataset.__len__()):
            batch: list = []
            for j in training_data:
                x_in = torch.tensor(data=j, device=device, dtype=torch.float)

                logits = my_net(x=x_in)
                x_in = logits

            # Make a prediction based on the training loop above
        prediction = nn.Softmax(dim=1)(x_in)
        y = prediction.argmax(1)
```

What would cause this error?

```
Tracestack:
C:\*\main.py:99: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  x_in = torch.tensor(data=j, device=device, dtype=torch.float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\*\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    logits = my_net(x=x_in)
  File "C:\*\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\*\main.py", line 65, in forward
    x = self.flatten(x)
  File "C:\*\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\*\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\flatten.py", line 46, in forward
    return input.flatten(self.start_dim, self.end_dim)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

I tried using `self.Flatten(start_dim=-1)/self.Flatten(start_dim=-1, end_dim=0)` in the Linear network, but neither of these solved the issue.